# how can I move certain type of file from one folder to another

Tags: windows, command-line

Command prompt
Can I move the specific type of file and also copying the folder structure to a new place?

I wish to using the Windows Command Prompt to perform a task replace my manual actions. I need to move files from a folder to another (e.g. 1.pdf to pdf folder) at the same time also want to copy the file structure from the original location

I did successful with copying file structure without content by 
XCOPY G:\MASTER*.* G:\CHECKSUM*.* /T/E 
as I don't want to copy all files in the original location, i only want one type of file to be moved

i also use 
cd G:\calculate
move *.md5 G:\checksum

But how can I do both at the same time? so that I don't need to sort the file by myself.

Comment: we're talking of? Linux/Windows/what?

Comment: please provide more details of what you are trying to achieve. How do you define type of file - a compressed file? a source file?

Comment: I wish to using the Windows Command Prompt to perform a task replace my manual actions. I need to move files from a folder to another (e.g. 1.pdf to pdf folder) at the same time also want to copy the file structure from the original location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Microsoft's Windows Resource Kit, then the Robocopy.exe utility will do this for you.  It is a command line utility which goes well beyond xcopy in its capability.
Check the Microsoft downloads website.

Comment: This has come included since Vista. The resource kit was in the XP/Win2003 era.

Comment: Thanks, besides the code my friend helped, I also download a GUI version of Robocopy to try.

Answer (score 1):

kind friends help me to modify my original one.

it works:
 1) copy the folders structure and 
 2) also select specific type of file to copy

xcopy e:\calculate\master*.jpg e:\calculate\checksum*.jpg /s

simple and easy!